# Handling large amounts of sockets

Tags: sockets, real-time

I am working on a project in which we have a desktop application that should be able to receive commands from a web application. To solve this issue, using sockets seems like a good approach (instead of long polling and various other techniques).

The desktop application also uses a web API, and this is secured with mutual authentication in SSL. The sockets should also be secured with SSL.

The question is: what is the best way to handle large amounts of sockets?

I have thought of a solution which involves using a "relay socket". Basically the desktop application creates a socket to [The Relay Station]. Whenever an action should be sent from the web application, the web app also creates a socket to the relay station.

The web app sends a command saying "relay [this] to [socket]".

This approach requires that:

- All the desktop-to-relay sockets must be persistent
- The desktop application must identify himself, so that the webapp can reference him in his commands
- The relay station needs to keep track of all the desktop application sockets, and map those to a unique identifier.

This gives me a good structure, but it also arises some questions:

- What should the identifier be?
- Is there a better way of sending commands from [WebApp] to the correct desktop application, without using such approach?

Comment: Not really a suitable question for Stackoverflow as it's not about specific coding issues... it's more conceptual and probably better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is conceptual and not about a specific coding problem

Comment: Note: *Sockets* are used by any network technology in todays computers (long polling, ...). Hence saying "I think using sockets instead of xxx" is just not possible. They all use them.